# Can't install libnss-resolve

Tags: apt, dependencies, systemd

I need to install this package since it's a dependence of an application I need to install. Whenever I try, I get the error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnss-resolve : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install `systemd`, however, I already have it, in a higher version (237-3ubuntu-10.3). I've tried everything I could find on google, but just can't find a solution. Could anyone help me?

@edit

```
Using:
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

@edit2
As requested:

```
libnss-resolve:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10
  Version table:
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
systemd:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.3
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.3
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

@edit3

Resolved. I went to the git repository, cloned, installed via dpkg, and configured everything manually. Better than nothging.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy libnss-resolve systemd` please?

Comment: @steeldriver Done

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update before trying the install?

Comment: Yes, ive tried everything i could find on google

Comment: Hmm - I wonder if you should have at least the `bionic-security` repos enabled in your sources.list? or more specifically if they were enabled and then disabled again

Comment: Could you help me doing that? i'm not really experienced on using the shell or linux at all.